# unable to create first api without web.xml in servlet

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, servlet-3.0

## i am used tomcat 9.0.12 and eclipse 2019 ##

here is my class

```
 package com.example.apidemotry;

    import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

    import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;



    @ApplicationPath("/rest")
    public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig{
        public MyApplication() {
            packages("com.example.apidemotry");

        }

    }
```

package com.example.apidemotry;

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/api")
public class DemoGet {


    @GET
    @Path("/msg")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String  getMsg() {
                    return "datageted";
    }

}
```

and api created like this

http://localhost:8080/apidemotry/rest/api/msg

but every time get HTTP Status 404 – Not Found , many time clean project and restart server but api created demo not working but any other servlet demo code is worked in this apache 9.0.12

can any one help me  or suggetion to develop web service witout web.xml?

Comment: What Jars or dependencies have you added to your project?

Comment: jercy server 3.0 all jar file downloaded and added in lib folder

you can download from here  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cspCd-Tsc1_gt934hGtngsh-eU2Hc2Qt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You do not have all the required jars. Download the jax-rs ri bundle from [here](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/download.html) and add _all_ the jars.

Comment: all jar files are added and code run in apache tomcat server and creating half url

http://localhost:8080/apidemotry/

can you provide any reference link to create web service without using web.xml

Comment: thank you man for helping me

Comment: You shouldn't need a web.xml if you have all the jars and a `ResourceConfig` subclass annotated with `@ApplicationPath`. Did you put all the jars in WEB-INF/lib? Do you have anything in your server log saying that the Jersey app is running?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha now services is working fine, i am missed 1 jar file adding web-inf/lib